# Change Cloudfront next origin file request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup a cloudfront system for a website.
To serve of the fly picture transformation, i added a custom origin, being the website.

So, in my distribution, i have 2 origins : 
 - s3 bucket
 - mywebsite.com/images

Wen i call cdn.mywebsite.com/500/picture.jpg
It will call my website like : website.com/api.php/file/500/picture.jpg

I get the s3 object, create the thumb, save it on server then upload to s3.
Up to here, it all works.

Now, i would like that the next request to this file does not go to my origin custom website, but to the s3 stored file.

I cannot find a way to define order of importance (weight) for multiple origins.

It seams that once frontcloud has a "route", it keeps the same one.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are correct, once CloudFront chooses which origin (based on path) it is done choosing.  There is, though, a way to do this that might work for you, if you don't mind a browser redirect when you hit a file that's not yet in S3.  I could write that up if it sounds worthwhile.

Comment: Ok, ill test a redirection with a 301 code perhaps ?

Comment: i am trying this at the moment, need more data to be sure, it seams to work sometimes, but not always.

Comment: The redirection does not seam to work better. I upload the new created file, redirected the image to the s3 location. after cache expire, it still queries the thumb generation instead of the s3 file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do multiple origins for a Cloud Front Distributions from the AWS side you have to customize this using either

1. Amazon CloudFront REST API
2. Bucket Explorer

Check this guide has both steps http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-create-distributions-post-distribution-with-multiple-origin-servers.html

Comment: It seams a lot of work just to do some "on the fly" thumb generation. I already upload the files to s3 bucket. I only want to serv transformed pictures 1 time. Then go back to normal s3 origin. I suppose i can just set a long TTL for all transformed pictures. Then no need to store them on S3. I also do not understand why we cannot do multiple origins, because they give the choice to do so...

Comment: We can do multiple origins but we have to programmatically tell Cloudfront which origin to use when it is not some thing cloud front handles automatically.

Comment: I have read all that article. It's exactly what i have done with the aws website interface. I am checking at the moment the caching mechanism, but i see nothing in Bucket Explorer i cannot do on the website.

Comment: I did not get your question?

Comment: I do not understand your response ;-) I have already created a distribution with multiple origins. I do not understand in that article what they do i do not. The screenshots are to small :-) I am guessing it's the behaviour part... but not sure. I am going to test out the redirection suggested by @Michael - sqlbot.